# unable open sharepoint central admin

Tags: 2010, central-administration

Following are the two unexpected errors i found in the log file 
Please help me out its urgent.......

1. Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalAvailable()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.EnsureMySiteUrls()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalMySiteUrlAvailable()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecu...
2. Unexpected  ...rsive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Try resetting application pool for your central admin app and then also try a IIS-reset. Maybe it will help.

Comment: thanks for the reply.... but problem is not solved..
its showing the same errors

Comment: Check if in CA, User profile services are started and also in windows service window check if related components are in started state.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. User profile service was stopped restarted and did iisreset everything is working file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when User profile isn't working you get this exception so in CA start User profile services and also in windows service window you need to ensure that related components are in started state too.

You can view old ULS logs to find out why this happened to stop this from reoccurring in future.